# Adding a column to a python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a python numpy ndarray with 2 numeric fields. Want to add a third field to it which is just the multiplication of the two. The two columns are named as "A" and "B" and I want the third column to be called "C". How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is [one way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html):

```
numpy.core.records.fromarrays([arr['A'], arr['B'], arr['A']*arr['B']], names='A,B,C')
```

[Another way](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.rec.html):

```
numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(arr, 'C', arr['A']*arr['B'])
```

Note that these will return a new array containing all the columns.  There's no way to add a column in-place.

Answer (score 0):

works too but more verbose

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.random.random_sample((10,2))
array_c = my_array[:,0]* my_array[:,1]
dt = [('A', float), ('B', float), ('C', float)]
my_array = np.column_stack((my_array, array_c)).astype(dt)
```